# How to use BeginInvoke for button.PerformClick() from another thread - cross threaded call

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, button, click

I have a method:

```
 private void RecordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

  }
```

and in the other method which was called by other thread:

```
 private void raiseAlarm() {
                RecordButton.PerformClick();//EXCEPTION HERE
        }
```

I get an exception that indicates the `PerformClick()` is invoked in the other thread therefore I should make a cross thread call. What should I write instead to `PerformClick()`?

Comment: are you using wpf  or winforms

Comment: @K.B Both in this app, but this is rather winforms part(this code is in WinForms class).

Comment: DO search in stackoverflow, there are lots of the same questions

Comment: @sll I did, there are only very specific ones and their problematics domain does not cover this question.

Comment: @sll Please have a glance at the comment under the answer please.

Answer (score 3):

here how  you can by pass  this exception

```
private void raiseAlarm()
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {

                Action action = raiseAlarm;  
                this.Invoke( action); 
            }
            else
            {

               RecordButton.PerformClick();
            }

        }
```

or you can  use BeginInvoke which executes the specified delegate asynchronously on the thread that the control's underlying handle was created on.

```
  private void raiseAlarm()
        {

            this.BeginInvoke(new Action(raiseAlarm)); 



        }
```

Comment: Is using BeginInvoke is better?

Comment: BeginInvoke will start an asynchronous event but I don't think  in your scenario  will change  more things

Comment: How would callin BeginInvoke(...) looked? I tried `BeginInvoke(RecordButton.PerformClick)` but it did not work -> wrong parameters.